# Question about custom routing in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have to admit in advance that I'm quite new to MVC, I've been going through the resources at www.asp.net/mvc, but I was wondering if you guys could help me with something.

I have been asked to create a ASP.NET version of an existing PHP website, this website has a huge number of existing links to it in a particular format, which I have to replicate in due to the amount of work to change all the existing links would be far too much.

The format of the existing links is;

```
/([A-Za-z0-9]{14})/([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)
```

My attempt at creating a custom route doesn't appear to be working. What I have done is change the RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax.cs file to be;

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "ExistingLink",
        "{LinkId}/{Title}",
        new {controller="ExistingLinkController", action="Index"},
        new {LinkId = @"([A-Za-z0-9]{14})", Title = @"([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)"});

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

I have also created the 'ExistingLinkController' with an 'Index' action of;

```
public ActionResult Index(string LinkId, string Title)
{
    ViewData["LinkId"] = LinkId;
    ViewData["Title"] = Title;
    return View();
}
```

And a view which contains the code;

```
<h2>LinkId: <%: ViewData["LinkId"] %>
</h2>Title: <%: ViewData["Title"] %></h2>
```

But when I try to go to;

> /55a3ef90c4b709/This-is-just-a-test_0-9

I get the following error;

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource
>   you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please
>   review the following URL and make sure
>   that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL:
>   /55a3ef90c4b709/This-is-just-a-test_0-9

I was wondering whether anyone can see what I am doing wrong and possibly point me in the right direction, perhaps pointing at the bit of code that's wrong if its a simple problem or pointing me to a article that will help me get a better understanding if I've got the wrong end of the stick with this routing stuff.

Thanks for any help in advance

Satal :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this:

```
 new {controller="ExistingLinkController", action="Index"},
```

Should just be this:

```
 new {controller="ExistingLink", action="Index"},
```

MVC adds the Controller part of the name itself - In the second route the controller is also called HomeController, but you only enter "Home" as the default for the controller argument.

Comment: Perfect thank you, I knew it would probably be something simple that I couldn't see due to lack of experience :D

Answer (score 2):

when i get stuck with my routes i use the route debugger from Phil Hack

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx

its just epic